# On while first item will have different class

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a simple while loop that will get the last 3 posts from WordPress.

Now when I have output HTML from this PHP all 3 wrappers will have class active. I need to have this 'active' class only on the first one on the second and the third one won't have this class.

I tried this when I add this class to wrapper but all wrapper will have this class.

Is there any option for how I can add class 'active' only on the first post from this while loop?

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
);

$post_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($post_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($post_query->have_posts()) {
        $post_query->the_post();
        ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" class="mySlides blog-slider active">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
    <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <div class="content">
            <strong><?php the_title();?></strong>
            <!-- <div class="smalls">
                <small>Alexander Martin</small>
                <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/smalls-divider.svg">
                <small>21min</small>
            </div> -->
            <p><?php the_excerpt('20')?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add any counter to check if you are at first item or not.

```
$i = 0;
while (...) {
    ...
    <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" class="mySlides blog-slider <?php echo $i === 0 ? 'active' : '' ?>">
    ...
    $i++;
}
```